# MVC httppost load model into controller, specify to load one attribute before another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a entity model being passed to my view with some hiddenfor's and editorfor's for appropriate fields.

When I submit the form, all of my members come across in the controller just fine. However, I extended my entity model to have an additional field for appending to a field.

```
        public string DescriptionAdd {
        get { return ""; }
        set { DescriptionHistory += DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy : hh:mm tt") + " by " + Core.Authorization.LoginUser.Current.FullName + " <span style='display:none;'>" + Core.Authorization.LoginUser.Current.EmailAddress + "</span> " + value + "<br />"; }
    }
```

Okay, everything seems fine so far.

When I hit save, however, the DescriptionHistory is null. When the controller actually gets stopped in debugger though, the DescriptionHistory has the original value.

This leads me to think that it's loading them in the wrong order. Is it possible to specify what order the members are bound?

Comment: This looks like very fragile code you are creating. Why would you want to do anything like this? I do not think the binding order is deterministic, it probably depends on the order of the variables posted back in the form or possibly in the xml/json if you are using ajax.

Comment: The idea is to have a history of notes that can't be destroyed/altered. Only appended to. I just decided to explicitly append the value in the controller.

The idea is that anyone who touches it later couldn't forget to append the new data in the controller and the functionality would be inherited by the structure.

My question though is that if it's possible to specify the order to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: Why not do this explicitly in the Action method of t he controller on Post using a method on the model or in the body of the action?

Comment: What trigger in your code invoke the DescriptionAdd set method? not clear.

Comment: Please post your entity model class..

Comment: It's not a trigger. When the Razor view engine submits the form, it creates the model before posting it to the controller. All I did was overload the setter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if I understand correctly that you want to save DescriptionHistory with some system driven value to the underlying table on Description column anytime save happens.

This is how you can accomplish it, by extending your original entity class

Ex: For your original entity generated as below

```
public partial class Employee
{
   public string Description
   {
      get;
      set;
   }
}
```

You will have extend and annotate with few tweaks, you can accomplish your needs

```
[MetaDataType(typeof(EmployeeMetaData))]
public partial class Employee
{
   [Column("Description")]
   public string DescriptionAdd
   {
      set { }
      get { return DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy : hh:mm tt") + " by " + Core.Authorization.LoginUser.Current.FullName + " <span style='display:none;'>" + Core.Authorization.LoginUser.Current.EmailAddress + "</span> " + value + "<br />"; }
   }
}

public class EmployeeMetaData
{
   [NotMapped]
   public string Description
   {
      get;
      set;
   }
}
```

Hope this meets your need.